# Automatically moving slider

Tags: html

I have a slider on one of my pages which has images of other companies next to each other.

There are arrow buttons to click to make the slider move but I would like the slider to move it self. Would this be possible?

I have tried some of the code I found on the web, but it doesn't seem to work with my code.

My Code:

```
<center><span class="title-head">Our Affiliates</span></center>
</h2>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="product-slide" class="owl-carousel owl-theme product-slide">
                    <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.fixauto.com"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/1.png" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Fix Auto</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>

                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                </div><!-- Item 1 end -->

                <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.customerloyalty.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Customer Loyalty Consultants</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                </div><!-- Item 2 end -->

                <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.commrisk.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Commrisk</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>

                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                </div><!-- Item 3 end -->

                <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.aon.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">AON</p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                </div><!-- Item 4 end -->

                <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.audatex.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/5.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Audatex</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.merxcu.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/6.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Merx</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.psg.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/7.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">PSG</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.galileorisk.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/8.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Galileo Capital</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->

                        <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.oldmutual.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/10.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Old Mutual</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->

                                                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.sha.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/11.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">S|H|A</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->

                                                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.pwvnorth.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/12.png" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">PWV Insurance Brokers</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                                                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="http://www.brolink.co.za"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/aff slider/13.png" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="product-title">Brolink</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->


                </div>
                </div><!-- Product slide -->
            </div><!-- Col end -->
        </div><!--/ Content row end -->
    </div><!--/ Container end -->
    <div class="down-arrow-white"></div>
</section><!-- Product area end -->
```

Comment: If you are using owl-carousel (assumed as you have a class there), check this link -> [Owl Carousel -
 Autoplay](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html)

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.